# Wagtail CMS(Django) - Display Inline Model Fields in Related Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have two custom models(not inheriting from `Page`) that are specific to the admin in a Wagtail CMS website. I can get this working in regular Django, but in Wagtail I can't get the inline model fields to appear. I get a `key error`. The code...

On `model.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.admin.panels import (
    FieldPanel,
    MultiFieldPanel,
    FieldRowPanel,
    InlinePanel,
)

from author.models import Author


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField("Date released")

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel('book_review'),
        ], heading="Book reviews"),
    ]


class BookReview(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_review')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    content = models.TextField()
    
    panels = [
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel('title'),
            FieldPanel('content'),
        ])
    ]
```

and `wagtail_hooks.py`:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin,
    modeladmin_register,
)
from .models import Book, BookReview


class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    add_to_admin_menu = True
    inlines = [BookReview] # only added this after key error, but it didn't help


modeladmin_register(BookAdmin)
```

How can I get the `InlinePanel('book_review'),` line to show up in the admin. It all works until I try add the inline model fields.

I looked around online and it was mentioning a third party Django `modelcluster` package. Is this still required? Those post were quite old(5 years or so). Or instead of using `ForeignKey` use `ParentalKey`, but that's only if inheriting from `Page` model.

Comment: You shouldn't have to include the `inlines` attribute on the ModelAdmin attribute. It should already work without itn as you specified the panel in the models. What error is it throwing exactly?

Comment: Yeah the `inlines` line I only added after error to try get working. I have removed it as it didn't help(when it wasn't working I was copying my vanilla Django setup to try get working). The error says `KeyError at /admin/books/book/create/` and under that line is `book_review`. So `KeyError` on the inline model I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Book model to inherit from ClusterableModel (which itself inherits from models.Model)

```
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

class Book(ClusterableModel):
```